# Jython ignores jythonpath

Tags: classpath, jython

My jython script is using Apache Tika, and it fails to load the Tika jar even though I placed it both in CLASSPATH and in PYTHONPATH. Here's what I'm doing:

```
> export JYTHONPATH=/full_path_to/tika-app-1.5.jar 
> export CLASSPATH=/full_path_to/tika-app-1.5.jar 
> java -Xmx512m -Xss1024k -jar /full_path_to/jython-standalone-2.7-b2.jar \
     -c 'from org.apache.tika import *'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named apache
```

I'm using Jython 2.7 beta 2 on OSX. Java version is 1.8:

```
> java -version 
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
```

The same thing is happening on Amazon's EC2 Linux with Java 1.7.

When I'm using the non-standalone version of the jython jar (jython-2.7-b2.jar instead of jython-standalone-2.7-b2.jar), it seems to be working okay.

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the problem. In Java, when using the -jar option, it more or less ignores the classpath. Just have to run the same code but with calling the jython 'main' class directly - not via '-jar'.